# ASP not reading all code text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file, server

I want to read file names from a server directory using ASP code.

I think the code is written correct, actually on log I am getting [this](https://ibb.co/jXpKc8) message, which is a part of my ASP code, but not the whole source code, so I don't get any result from it.

Here is my JS code:

```
function getFilesList() {
    $('#fileList').empty();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            $('<option>').text(this.responseText).appendTo('#fileList');
        }
    }
    xhttp.open('GET', scriptPath + 'getFiles.asp', true);
    xhttp.send();
    $('#loadFile').show();
}   //function getFilesList() ends here
```

and the ASP code:

```
<%
Dim objFSO, objFile, objFolder

Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("/web/Recipes"))

For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    Response.Write objFile.Name & "<br>"
Next
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
```

I would like to mention that the path structure is the following: *server/web/Recipes/the files I need*.

My question is why ASP is not reading the whole code, or what can I do for it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ASP code isn't running the server side code you need. Load it directly in the browser (which will do the exact same as your Javascript) - You are using classic ASP which is older than ASP.NET - this article might help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

Once it's installed, load the web server page directly to check it works, then worry about your Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Paul, will try to configure it this way